# meta tag html index page

Tags: html, meta-tags

I developed a site but I've got some problems to index it. I've got 10 pages but when I search my site on google the first result is the page "contact" and not "index". I have included title and meta tag description and keywords in the index page but the result is the always the same.

Comment: You should post this question on Webmasters.SE

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue. Google decides what it shows first and second. For some reason, it has decided that your contact page is more relevant than your index page for your query. For other queries, that might be different.

You can check for other [site indexing issues](https://ligatures.net/content/expertise/site-not-indexing-checklist.html) with a checklist I created if you have other issues.